# A decimal Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe type formula for the Bring radical of 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, algorithms, algebraic-numbers

The [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) yields a hexadecimal spigot algorithm for the mathematical constant $\frac{\tau}{2} = \pi$. Does there exist a decimal (base 10) Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe type formula for the Bring radical of 1, $\operatorname{Br}(1)$, defined implicitly as $\operatorname{Br}(1)^5 + \operatorname{Br}(1) + 1 = 0$?

Comment: "... for the mathematical constant $\frac{\tau}{2} = \pi$" Shots fired...

Comment: Note that $x^5 + x + 1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)$.  Presumably you want the real root, so it is the real root of $x^3-x^2+1$, namely $$
-{\frac {\sqrt [3]{100+12\,\sqrt {69}}}{6}}-{\frac {2}{3\,\sqrt [3]{
100+12\,\sqrt {69}}}}+{\frac{1}{3}}
$$.